# How can i create tables on shell with manage.py sql output?

Tags: django, django-models

syncdb don't create tables from ManyToMany fields, soh if i do "python manage.py sql" the output brings code to create then.

Comment: open dbshell and execute the query there.

Comment: What database engine are you using ?